# Installing sen2cor on Anaconda 4.4.0

Tags: python, anaconda, sen2cor

I would like to install sen2cor in Anaconda 4.4.0 virtual env. 
How to know the list of dependencies needed? Is there environment.yaml file for sen2cor?

Comment: What OS are you working with?

Answer (score 1):

I found this, still not able to use it properly so far
https://anaconda.org/terradue/sen2cor

```
conda install -c terradue sen2cor
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a docker container for sen2cor. There is one at https://github.com/lvhengani/sen2cor_docker.